# Minecraft 1.6.4 doesn't install

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't get Minecraft 1.6.4. I downloaded the new launcher on minecraft.net, but it's still 1.6.2.  When I click on "edit profile," there's no 1.6.4 displayed.

Comment: Where are you looking in the profile editor?

Comment: @Unionhawk it might not be, it seems he did go into edit profile but 1.6.4 was simply not an option

Comment: @TheUgly That's not possible unless they have no internet connection.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Alright, I didn't know for sure.